# Using Spreading spectral with Maximal likelihood

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, spread-spectrum

As asked here, [HERE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/55623/using-mimo-with-ds-cdma-and-spread-spectrum/55625?noredirect=1#comment111696_55625)  if we have the signal

```
x = 
[0.7 + 0.7i; 
0.7 - 0.7i;
-0.7 + 0.7i;
-0.7 -0.7i];
```

Which was spread over code `c` and transmitted over channel `H` whose dimension is [4x4], so the convolution of signal after spreading will become:

```
r = reshape(H*reshape(x,4,[]),[],1);
```

comparing it with signal without spreading, it was

```
 r = H*x;
```

That was explained well in the above link.

My question, suppose I am using Maximum likelihood estimation, in case if we didn't spread the signal, we will check the likelhood compared with the channel `H`, but what's about after using spreading ? how will become the channel ? It supposed to be a vector of [16x1], is that right ? but how will it be ?

thank you!

Comment: Please simply consider a single channel, not a whole channel matrix for a start; makes way more sense here, because the same is happening for the other channels, too. Would this simplification get you going?

Comment: Yes I got your idea, but i'm working now with single channel too, which is MIMO. the difference which I'm looking for is before spreading and after spreading

Comment: "single channel, which is MIMO" is a self-contradiction. (MIMO literally means multiple input, multiple output: You hence have multiple point-to-point channels.) You're confusing the vocabulary, and as much as I try, I don't understand you.

Comment: And as far as I can tell, your question is not about a space-time block code, is it?

Comment: you really *don't* understand MIMO well, we've had this exact discussion before: whether or not your individual point-to-point channels need to be convolved (i.e. have multiple taps, are frequency-selective) or are just coefficients (i.e. can be just multiplied coefficients from a matrix, are flat) has **nothing** to do with it being MIMO or not. You're seriously mixing up very basic things. And that's been going on for weeks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H was not reshaped, as you see in your command `r = reshape(H*reshape(x,4,[]),[],1);`, you reshaped the data itself.

In that case, you are going to add noise, then using ML estimation based on the received data. So that, H will be H without changing, what will be changed is the received data, you can reshape it similar to that way in the transmitter `reshape(y,4,[])`, where y is the received data, then reshape the results again into [16 x 1].

Good luck